# check uri content with powershell and alert for string match

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am executing this code:

```
$web = Invoke-WebRequest http://x.x.x.x:60210/CoreApi/api/Healthcheck
$web.tostring()
```

The response in `$web` is as below.

> HealthStatus:DBConnectionSuccess:True EventStoreConnectionSuccess:True UnpublishedEvents:0 AzureBusConnectionSuccess:True Errors:NONE

I need to create an alert for condition UnpublishedEvents:[>10]. Can someone help me with just the string match logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic solution using a regular expression:

```
$output = 'HealthStatus:DBConnectionSuccess:True EventStoreConnectionSuccess:True UnpublishedEvents:11 AzureBusConnectionSuccess:True Errors:NONE'

$unpublishedEvents = 0

$regex = 'UnpublishedEvents:([0-9]+)'

$match = [regex]::match($output, $regex)
if ($match.Success)
{
  $unpublishedEvents = $match.Groups[1].Value
}

if ($unpublishedEvents -gt 10)
{
  Write-Host "Some alert! ($unpublishedEvents events)"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression with a named capture group to do that, like this:

```
$input = "HealthStatus:DBConnectionSuccess:True EventStoreConnectionSuccess:True UnpublishedEvents:20 AzureBusConnectionSuccess:True Errors:NONE"
$isMatch = $input -match "UnpublishedEvents:(?<UnpubEventCount>\d+)"
if ($isMatch)
{
    return $Matches.UnpubEventCount -gt 10
}
else
{
    Write-Error "UnpublishedEvents not found"
}
```

`$Matches` is a "magic" variable that is set when using the `-match` operator.